# SQL View returning filtered data from unnormalized table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to create a view from table which must contain only the newest elements from a set of duplicates. It is an easy task, but the problem is that the table is not normalized. Each record is identified by three string columns: Transponder, Country and System. I cannot introduce any change in the database structure. The newest elements should be returned basing on Time column. So having such data:

```
Transponder | Country | System  | Time
--------------------------------------------
AAA         | BBB     | CCC     | 2012-01-01
AAA         | BBB     | CCC     | 2010-01-01
AAA         | BBB     | CCC     | 2013-01-01
AAA         | BAB     | DDD     | 2011-01-01
AAA         | BAB     | DDD     | 2010-01-01
```

I want my view to return only two rows:

```
AAA         | BBB     | CCC     | 2013-01-01
AAA         | BAB     | DDD     | 2011-01-01
```

How can I achieve this? I use Postgresql 9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct on (transponder, country, system) * from some_table
order by transponder, country, system, time desc
```

Answer (score 1):

select transponder, country, system max(time) from TABLE group by transponder, country, system;

This will give you the distinct record aggregated across the grouped records (transponder, country, system for the aggregated column (in this case time).

Answer (score 0):

Postgre isn't my thing, but this looks just like a group by SQL statement problem:

```
SELECT transponder, country, system, MAX(time)
  FROM your_table
GROUP BY transponder, country, system
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use...

```
SELECT  Transporter ,
        Country ,
        [System] ,
        [TIME]
FROM    ( SELECT    Transporter ,
                    Country ,
                    [System] ,
                    [TIME] ,
                    RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Transporter, Country, [System] ORDER BY [TIME] DESC ) AS [order]
          FROM      tableName
        ) AS a
WHERE   a.[order] = 1
```

I need to double check syntax for `PostgresSQL` though.